# What is heat bath here?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, entropy, kinetic-theory-of-gases

At the beginning $\pu{1 mol}$ of air is compressed to $\pu{3 atm}$ at a of temperature $\pu{523 K}$. After a random process, the pressure of the air equates to $\pu{1 bar}$ at a temperature of $\pu{353 K}$. A amount of heat is transferred to a bath of $\pu{303 K}$.

Where does the heat come from? From the gas? Or the bath is the gas?

Comment: The bath is envisioned as a liquid at a constant temperature of 303 K.  The heat flows from the gas to the bath, driven by the higher temperature of the gas.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.  It includes an option to describe measurements (like $T = \pu{300 K}$ by `$T = \pu{300 K}$`), so unwanted line breaks between the number and the symbol of the unit may be prevented, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In voluntary / spontaneous processes, heat is passed from the reservoir of higher energy to the one of lower energy.  Thus, heat from the reservoir of higher temperature transfers to the reservoir of lower temperature, until both share the same temperature.  The reverse is possible only if you invest work.

As an analogy, compare the situation with a [pumped-stage hydroelectric plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity), where energy is stored in the potential energy of the water in the upper basin.